# Checking if first characters of a string contains values from array

Tags: php, arrays

I need a function in PHP which checks, if one array value is in a the first characters of a string, but the array values contains different number of characters.

The function should also check the longer array values first, because it should only find the longest array value.

Example:

```
$string = 'ausspielen'; // should give 'aus' as result
$string2 = 'auseinandernehmen'; // should give 'auseinandernehmen' as result
$string3 = 'einarbeiten'; // should give 'ein' as result
$string4 = 'einherfahren'; // should give 'einher' as result
$array  = ['aus','auseinander','ein','einher'];
```

I can use `mb_substr($string, 0, 3);` to find the first three characters, but how it is possible to find different numbers of characters?
I have also found the function `strpos`, which finds the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string, but how to apply this for my problem?

My goal is to find the correct value from the array for the strings. For example the string `'auseinandernehmen'` should find the array value `'auseinander'` and not `'aus'`.
The function should check the first characters of a string and compare them with all values of an array, but if it finds a longer array value it should use this, not the short one like `'aus'`. The result should be the longest array value, which the function founds.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Please read the updated text.

Comment: `'auseinandernehmen' should find the array value 'auseinander'` So where is `'auseinander'` in your array. Your requirement must make sense

Comment: Also **SO is not** a free Coding service ___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the clue is passing the $array sorted by length of its elements from longer descending:

```
function Match($aString){

    $array  = ['auseinander','einher','aus','ein'];

    foreach($array as $elem){
        if (substr($aString,0,strlen($elem))==$elem)  // Beginning of $aString matches element of $array
            return $elem;
    }
    return "";
}

echo Match('ausspielen') ."\n";
echo Match('auseinandernehmen') . "\n";
echo Match('einarbeiten') . "\n";
echo Match('einherfahren') . "\n";
```

The output is as you expect:

```
aus
auseinander
ein
einher
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For this function I have to change my array values  sequence first the longer ones and then the short ones.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is the logic you are asking to know, so as an advice it would be best to try it on your own a bit.

But the solution is pretty much clear: Create a for loop which will iterate through every string, find its' position with strpos, and use this position and the mb_str as you want to get the first nth characters.

The criteria of how this number of characters will be chosen is based on what you want to do. You can have switch cases or if statements which check your strings and decide respectively what to keep for each one. If you take this data from a database, it would be good to have a more formal format, in order to be able to manage it better.

Comment: *"But the solution is pretty much clear"*: there are nothing obvious to build an efficient algorithm, even if a solution seems obvious *(to you)*.

Comment: Yes, sorry if my answer seemed rude, I thought about it after. The main reason I said it, is because the way you are asking it is basically what I said is needed to be done. I don't know if I helped you, I just explained the logic you were describing at first, as a hint to figure out the solution itself. Sorry again if I was misunderstood :)

Comment: Don't worry, anyway I'm not sure to understand the question.